# Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param “state” missing

Tags: php, facebook, session, authentication, fbsdk

I have uploaded this code for solving facebook login problem. there're 3 files to implement this.. `(login.php/playground_fb.php/member_index_fb.php)` ... First you can find the simple button for `href` to `playground_fb.php`. and then there's some algorithm in `playground_fb.php` and then finally if user accept this app, then go to the `member_index_fb.php` with info sessions such as email address, first name, last name... I have searched a lot about these problems, but I only found the advice like input the `session_start` or stop the sessions or keep in '`www`' like this... But it still remain unchanged... Who else help me please?

```
<!-- login.php -->          
<div onclick="facebookLogin()" style="cursor: pointer;" align="center">
                <img src="../build/img/login/login_facebook.png">
            </div>  

function facebookLogin() {  
    top.location.href = 'http://www.peeknchews.com/playground_fb.php';
}
```

---

```
<!-- playground_fb.php --> 
<?php
  session_start(); 
  require_once('/home/kukkim/peeknchews.com/build/apis/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php'); 

  $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '257184091349723',
  'app_secret' => '6c079349483a1bc959ce515df4e8138a',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
  ]);



  $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

  try {
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
      $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    }
    else {
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
  }
  catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    //When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }
  catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    //When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
    exit;
  }



  if(!isset($accessToken)) {

      $permissions = ['email']; // optional
      $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/playground_fb.php', $permissions);

      // die($_SESSION['FBRLH_' . 'state']);

      echo "<script> top.location.href = '$loginUrl'; </script>";

      // $permissions = ['email']; // optional
      // $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.peeknchews.com/playground_fb.php', $permissions);

      // echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">LOG IN WITH FACEBOOK!</a>';


  }

  else {

      if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
      }

      else {
        // Logged in!
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler 
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short lived access token for a long lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
      }

      try {
        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,name');
        $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
      }
      catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returne d an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        exit;
      }
      catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returend an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
      }

      $fbId = $userNode->getId();
      $fbEmail = $userNode->getProperty('email');
      $fbName = $userNode->getName();
      $fbFirstName = $userNode->getProperty('first_name');
      $fbLastName = $userNode->getProperty('last_name'); 

      $_SESSION['fbId'] = $fbId;
      $_SESSION['fbEmail'] = $fbEmail;
      $_SESSION['fbName'] = $fbName;


      echo 'Name: ' . $fbName;
      echo "<br>";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $fbId . '<br>';
      echo 'Email: ' . $fbEmail . '<br><br>'; 
      echo 'Firstname : ' . $fbFirstName . '<br><br>'; 
      echo 'Lastname : ' . $fbLastName . '<br><br>'; 


      $image = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbId . '/picture?width=100';
      echo "Picture<br><br>";
      echo "<img src='$image' /><br><br> ";


      //Now you can redirect to another page and use the
      // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
      echo "<script>top.location.href = 'http://www.peeknchews.com/member_index_fb.php';</script>";

  }

?>
```

---

```
<!-- member_index_fb.php -->
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('/home/kukkim/peeknchews.com/build/apis/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php'); 
  $sessionEmail=$_SESSION['user_email'];  

  //facebook
  $fbSessionId = $_SESSION['fbId'];
  $fbSessionEmail = $_SESSION['fbEmail'];
  $fbSessionName = $_SESSION['fbName'];

  require_once('/home/kukkim/peeknchews.com/config.php'); 
?>

          <li>
            <a class="nav-login fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="php_login/login.php"><img src="build/img/icons/login.png">
              <?php 
                echo "<br>";
                echo $fbSessionName . "<br>";  
                echo $fbSessionEmail . "<br>"; 


                $image = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbSessionId . '/picture?width=100';
                echo "<img src='$image' /><br><br> ";
              ?>
            </a>
          </li>
```